# How to fit math function to the dataset in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, curve-fitting, scatter-plot

I have three sets of data as shown below:
[image]

I wonder what is the function they follow and how to fit these curves in Python?

I guess the first function is something like:

> y = ax<sup>b</sup> + cx + d

I tried some arbitrary parameters:

```
x = numpy.arange(1,10000,2.)
a = 100.
b = -0.003 
c = 50.
d = 0.1
y = -a/x**d+b*x+c
scatter(x,y)
```

The figure shows like this:

[image]

Anyone could help with the other two?

Comment: Looks like a pretty good fit. What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for all your help. I got a solution from my friends.

```
y = -a/x**d+b*x+c
```

Since d makes the fit complicated, it will be easier to set d from 0.1 to 1.0, then use the curve_fit to fit the model. Finally find the best parameter set.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve this, as a total beginner with NumPy and SciPy:

First, create a Python function that we think calculates `y` for every `x`. (This equation is in the question above.)

```py
def fx(x, a, b, c, d):
    return -a / x**d + b*x + c
```

Then we need some data from the graph, which was not included in the question, so I guessed a bit, using the green graph in the question:

```py
x = [0.01, 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000]
y = [1, 1.67, 1.75, 1.67, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4]
```

(x = 0 is an invalid point, since `0**d` is 0, and we can't divide by zero. That's why I say "0.01" instead.)

Then we let SciPy calculate what the constants should be:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fx, x, y)
print(popt)
```

This results in "RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found". We can help by manually guessing a value for `d`:

```py
def fx(x, a, b, c):
    d = -0.1
    return -a / x**d + b*x + c
```

The `popt` variable will contain values for `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
[-5.64063556e-01 -6.55610681e-05  6.41890483e-01]
```

It's helpful to use a graph calculator like [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) when experimenting like this, and trying out different values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in scipy that can be used to fit a function to data: [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit).

Comment: Can I fit the model directly if d is less than 1?